# c++: function pointer with template

Tags: c++, templates, function-pointers

```
void func1(int){}
void func2(char){}

template <typename T> void (*p)(T);   // error
p = func1;
p = func2;
```

Why cant we define a pointer like `p`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @SergeyA and @Brian 's help, I solved the problem and I edit my answer here.

`template<typename T> void (*p)(T)`: in this case, `p` is a variable template(c++14). So we can use `p` like this:

```
p<int> = func1;
p<char> = func2;
```

`template<class T> using p = void (*)(T)`: in this case, `p` is a kind of type(it's just like `typedef` but we cant use `typedef` for alias template). Meaning that we should use it like this:

```
p<int> x1 = func1;
p<char> x2 = func2;
```

Btw, both of them are `template declaration`, so we can't put them at any block scope.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it like this:

```
template<class T> using p = void (*)(T);

void f(int );
p<int> x = &f;
```

Comment: Downvote? Can the honorable downvoter please explain what is the problem with my answer?

Comment: Probably the OP because he was wanting to write `p = func1;` without any template args.

Comment: @kfsone, that would not be possible anyways.

Answer (score 3):

C++14 actually allows variable templates, so your definition of the template `p` is valid.

However, `p` is a variable template, not a variable; in order to get an actual variable, you need to instantiate it with a particular type, like so:

```
p<int> = func1;
p<char> = func2;
```

Comment: In OP's example, `p` is a type, not a variable.

Comment: @SergeyA I beg to differ. If you compile with C++14, `p` is a variable template.

Comment: @SergeyA OP seems to be trying to make a variable which will accept a pointer to either a `void (*)(int)` or a `void (*)(void)`.

Comment: @kfsone, may be... OP was notably vague in their intention.

Comment: @Brian, I think, I am not clear as to what OP actually wants to do. You might be correct in your understanding of OP's goals.

Comment: @SergeyA  Can you tell me why it is a type with c++11? Is it because `p` hasn't been instantiated? I'm confused now. I can understand Brian's explanation.

Comment: @Thomas, in C++11 it is neither a type nor variable, it is a syntax error. Now, in my understanding, it looks quite similar to old C++98 pointer-to-function type declaration, and I assumed this is what you want, and I gave my answer along those lines. Now, Brian sees that as an attempt to declare a template variable per C++14, and gave answer accordingly. Only you know who is correct in understanding of your question!

Comment: @SergeyA   OK, I think I understand what you want to say. If I compile `template<typename T> void (*p)(T);` with c++11, I will get a warning: `variable templates only available with c++14`. Meaning that this `p` is regarded as a kind of variable. If I compile `template<class T> using p = void (*)(T);` with c++11, it works. Here `p` is a type just like you said so we can use it like `p<int>`.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, the variable `p` is able to be assigned objects of unrelated types (here, two incompatible function pointers). Such a dynamic change in apparent type is not supported by templates, which are strictly static (compile-time) constructs.

If you want to achieve such a type-shifting object, *type erasure* techniques must be applied. In that specific case, [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) looks like it could be of use to you, but you still need to decide on a fixed function signature (how would you call it otherwise ?).